# Bootstrap 3 Nav header wraps between 768 and 992 pixels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I have 5 items in my navigation header that are kind of "wordy". When the screen size is between 768px and 992px, the menu items wrap to the line below my brand. This causes some pages to have their content hidden since my body tags padding-top is not adjusted to the nav height.

Once it goes below 768px, then it transitions to the default collapsed menu items that bootstrap does for everything.

I'm kind of lost on how to do this. Should I modify the media breakpoints to accommodate for my "minimum menu size", so when when it goes below that, it just transitions to the collapsible version instead of wrapping the lines/text? Or should I be manipulating the container size, etc?

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Here's the site: http://wrestlestat.apphb.com

Note: as a temporary fix, I just made my bodies "padding-top" bigger to accomodate the wrapping until I can get the proper fix.

Comment: I would just decrease the font-size (personal preference).  You have it hard-coded into the elements at 20px, which is bigger than most people would need.  If you really like it 20px at the full-size, you could put the 20px in a class, then do a media query to decrease that font-size at the tablet width.

Comment: Never thought of that....good answer (you should add it as one)

Comment: okay, added as an answer.  Glad it helped :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the CSS with a media query to collapse the navbar at 990 pixels like this..

http://www.bootply.com/117227

```
@media (max-width: 990px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, should be very straight-forward and easy. Should I place this in my own css file (along with migrating all my other custom css stuff), or place it directly in my layout page?

Comment: I'd recommend putting it in a separate CSS file